# Does amazon SNS support window desktop notification?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

Does Amazon SNS support notifications for windows desktop?

I am quite new to push notification services. I want to enable push notifications in my project. I was searching for and I read that Amazon SNS can send push notifications to Windows Mobile and iOS mobiles. But I want to enable notification in my web app also.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, SNS supports Windows push via WNS http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-wns.html

It also supports Windows Phone.